# HQL table named "Class"

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate.search

I'm creating hql and use

```
var queryString = "from " + formType.Name;
        queryString += " where Id= :t";
        var query = SessionHelper.GetSession().CreateQuery(queryString).SetParameter("t", id);
```

My problem is that I have table named "Class" and model Class.. So problem is that sometime formType.Name is Class and I get queryString as
from Class where Id= :t 
and as class is keyword that throws me QuerySyntaxException. How to tell query that Class is entity name instead keyword. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks in your mapping

```
<class name="´Class´">
```